# Formatting a hook array from different inputs in a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Suppose I have a hook in my React functional component like this:

```
function AddContactForm() {
    const [contactData, setContactData] = useState([]);

   ....
```

I want to pass this hook to a `POST` request to create a new contact record. This component is essentially a form with several inputs like this:

```
<form onSubmit={mySubmitHandler}>
  <p>Complete the Contact Information and hit submit:</p>
  <input type='text' name='name' id='name' onChange={myChangeHandler}/>
  <input type='text' name='title' id='title' onChange={myChangeHandler}/>
  <input type='text' name='email' id='email' onChange={myChangeHandler}/>
  <input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' onChange={myChangeHandler}/>
  <br />
  <button className="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Basically I want to use my `onChange` or `onSubmit` handler to populate/set the `contactData` hook to look like this:

```
[{"contact":"Joe Jones", "contact_title":"Mayor", "contact_email":"jjones@mycity.com", "contact_phone":"999-665-3333" }]
```

How would I use setContactData to set my hook up in the above format?

Answer (score 1):

So for this is I suggest to use a state management like `redux` or `zustand`
but in case you dont know those the best way is to create a hook for each value

like

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
....
```

and update each input

```
<input
  type='text'
  name='name'
  id='name'
  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

at the end, you can have an object to send with POST method

```
const data = {
  name,
  title,
  ...
}

const onsubmit = () => {
   API_FUNCTION_TO_SEND(data)
}
```

this works but get messy with large data
use `zustand` instead